# Problemas con la propiedad disabled en Angular me devuelve error "TS2322"

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

estoy realizando un formulario reactivo con Angular y quiero deshabilitar uno de sus campos , para eso coloque la propiedad 'disabled' en el input pero resulta que me devuelve un error , si bien solucioné el problema de otra forma, quisiera saber que es lo que está ocurriendo.
Codigo:

```html
<input formControlName="value" placeholder=" $0,0" disabled>
```

Me devuelve lo siguiente:  `error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean'`.

También intente colocando:

```html
<input formControlName="value" placeholder=" $0,0" disabled="disabled">
```

Y el error continua , si bien lo solucioné agregandole una clase:

```html
<input formControlName="value" placeholder=" $0,0" class="isDisabled">
```

Clase css:

```css
.isDisabled {
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: not-allowed;
}
  
  

.isDisabled:hover {
    cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

Me intriga saber que está sucediendo , agradezco la respuesta y el interés ante este sencillo problema

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir la parte de la clase, para ver cómo estás definiendo el formulario y el campo correspondiente al input?

Comment: Gracias por responder ahí detallé la clase, el formulario es  reactivo , pero lo utilicé en un formulario en un formulario por template y sucedió lo mismo

Comment: Me refería a clase JavaScript (es decir, la lógica en TypeScript de cómo estás configurando el formulario).

Comment: Que ese error te salga para lo que estas intentando es muy extraño, pon parte de código donde estas creando el FormGroup para ver a mas detalle, una recomendación que da angular "Es que al usar ([formControl], formControl Name, etc.) en un input no uses la directiva de disabled directamente sobre el input si no que lo uses con las funciones del FormControl, FormGroup. Ejemplo: nombre: FormControl = new FormControl({value:'Andres', disable: true}); ó nombre: FormControl; nombre.disabled();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando usas reactive forms lo ideal para deshabilitar tu input es :

```
this.form.get("elFormControlNameDeTuCampo").disabled()
```

De otra manera te saldrán errores por parte de angular recomendandote este cambio.

Answer (score 1):

Tu error `'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean'` se debe a que estás pasando un `string` cuando este atributo espera un `booleano` (true/false).

Pero fuera de ese error, la solución sería **no** utilizar la propiedad `disabled` directamente en el input sino directamente en tu componente cuando contruyes el formulario, de esta manera:

```
form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
  enabled: new FormControl(""),
  disabled: new FormControl({ value: "", disabled: true })
});
```